# How can I prove $tr(ST) = tr(TS)$ for two linear operators on a finite dimensional Hilbert space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I would like to know how to prove that  $$tr(ST) = tr(TS)$$ for two linear 
operators $S$ and $T$ on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, given the following definition of the trace operator: $$tr(T)=\sum_{i=1}^n{\langle T e_i, e_i \rangle}$$

for an orthonormal basis $\{ e_i \}_{i=1}^n$ in $\mathcal{H}$. Is there a way to prove this without representing the operators as matrices?

Comment: You may find worthwhile [the related blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/) by T. Tao: 
The cyclic property of the trace is derived, and explicit choices of orthonormal bases are not made.
Along the way you encounter a central relation connecting trace and determinant:
$\,\det(1 +\epsilon A) = 1+\epsilon\operatorname{tr}A+\text{O}(\epsilon^2)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this is different from writing an operator as a matrix, but you can argue as follows: for any operator $U$ you can write 
$$U(\cdot) = \sum_j U(e_j) \langle  \cdot , e_j \rangle$$ and thus for the trace of $ST$ you can find:
$$Tr(ST) = \sum_{i,j} \langle S(e_j), e_i \rangle \langle T(e_i), e_j \rangle $$
Now in the last formula you can commute the terms in the product. Hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of boils down to looking at matrices but you may decompose the identity as:
  $$ 1 = \sum_j  |e_j \rangle \langle e_j| $$
which inserted in the trace yields
$$ {\rm tr} (ST) = \sum_i \langle e_i |ST e_i\rangle =
   \sum_i \sum_j  \langle e_i |S e_j\rangle \langle e_j | T e_i \rangle $$
and you may interchange the sums and the two factors in the product.